# What does the new button on the power control widget do?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, app-widgets

There are 6 buttons on my power control widget:
[image]
WiFi, Bluetooth, GPS, ???, Data sync, Screen brightness.
What does the 4th one do?

P.S. I'm using an Orange San Francisco (ZTE Blade) with the '[Japanese Jellyfish RLS6](http://android.modaco.com/content/zte-blade-roms-rom-customisation/327579/rom-froyo-japanese-jellyfish-rls6-2011-01-09-oled-tft/)' custom FroYo ROM, but I've seen this power widget in other ROMS.

Comment: Which phone and which custom ROM?

Comment: Dunno. Don't have it on my Droid.

Comment: Dunno. Don't have it on my Incredible.

Comment: Are you using an app like "Extended Power Controls" which modifies the widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's either a **mobile network data enabled switch** or a 2G/3G switch, try it and check your data connection.

Edit: got confirmation, see comments.

Comment: Looks like it could possibly be for mounting/unmounting the SDcard also.

Comment: I doubt that because the rom release notes say that apndroid was removed due to this widget's new features, and apndroid controls the data connection.

Comment: Aha! Yep, it's the 'Mobile networks > Data enabled' switch (doesn't affect the 2G/3G setting). Do you want to amend your answer and I'll accept it.